# Fedex label creation issue in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex, labels

I am facing below issue in Fedex but i configured correctly in fedex in front end that same credentials working fine it gave quote for the product while shipping and only issue in label creation.

```
stdClass Object(
[HighestSeverity] => ERROR
[Notifications] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Severity] => ERROR
        [Source] => prof
        [Code] => 1000
        [Message] => Authentication Failed
    )

[TransactionDetail] => stdClass Object
    (
        [CustomerTransactionId] => *** Express International Shipping Request using PHP ***
    )

[Version] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ServiceId] => ship
        [Major] => 19
        [Intermediate] => 0
        [Minor] => 0
    )

)
```

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: Yes resolved...issue in fed ex they fixed

Comment: In my site the shipping cost displays good, but on the order page, shipment label creation error, who I need to contact?

Comment: What response is coming from FedEx? like above I mentioned?

Comment: My credentials are correct but I got authentication failed response. So, I contacted FedEx to enable the access for my account then it's working fine for me label also created